# .val() is returning undefined .text returning random code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I am having an issue with `.val()` returning an unexpected output I am using an item in an array to create a selector for an ID of a number input and then retrieving its value.

The input this should point to:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label>Strength</label>
    <input class="attributes form-control" id="strength" type="number" min="1" max="300" value="50" />
</div>
```

javaScript / jQuery:

```
$.each(traitName, function (key, value) {

if (binConv(traitRaces[key], 12).charAt(race) + binConv(traitClasses[key], 4).charAt(baseClass) == 00 && $("#startrunes li[data-value='" + key + "']").length <= 0) {

  $("#startrunes")
   .append($("<li title='Costs:" + traitCost[key] + " Requirement: " + traitRequireStat0[key] + "" + traitRequireValue0[key] + "' data-cost='" + traitCost[key] + "' data-value='" + key + "' class='ui-widget-content'></li>")
   .text(value));

}
else if (binConv(traitRaces[key], 12).charAt(race) + binConv(traitClasses[key], 4).charAt(baseClass) != 00) {

  $("#startrunes li[data-value='" + key + "']").remove();

}

if (traitRequireStat0[key].length > 0) {

  alert(parseInt($('#' + traitRequireStat1[key]).val(),10));
  if ($('#'+traitRequireStat0[key]).val() < traitRequireValue0[key]) {
      $("#startrunes li[data-value='" + key + "']").remove();
  }
}
else if (traitRequireStat1[key].length > 0) {
  if ($('#' + traitRequireStat1[key]).val() < traitRequireValue1[key]) {
      $("#startrunes li[data-value='" + key + "']").remove();
  }
}
```

The alert in the jQuery return NaN if I alert the val without parse int it comes back as undefined and if I use `.text()` I get random code all the arrays in here are equivalent length arrays and I don't believe them to be the root of the issue I am trying to get the current user input value not the value attribute.

Edit: forgot to mention the environment is jQuery / Bootstrap / jQuery UI

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: http://www.tacticalkaos.com/CharacterBuilder.aspx I decided to provide the entire project here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.text()` - cos it functions

Comment: @WilliamDunn ok, give me more html, cos u use key in each and i dont know what array do u have

Comment: coolm what i have to click or change? and what i have to get, but dont get cos of errors?

Comment: ack sorry the code I am concerned about activates after race and class are selected it will then activates the alert above

Comment: currently its set to parseInt so returns Nan instead of the value of the associated number input

Comment: so, u get trouble in getting value inside each, right?

Comment: yes when i try to get the val of the number inputed (strngth,dexterity) within that .each I get NaN,undefined, or random code if I use .text()

Comment: I tested the pointer if I have it just alert traitRequireStat1[key] it returns the proper point in the array

Comment: w8 a sec pls, u have a huge amount of code, its a little bit hard to understand all) i try now

Comment: traitRequireStat1 first - it is array woth only one  elem and other is "" - so thats why u get undefined, cos u have `$('#').val()`

Comment: u have to add a condition on if elem.exist

Comment: `if ($('#' + traitRequireStat1[key]).length > 0 ){
       alert(parseInt($('#' + traitRequireStat1[key]).val(),10));}`

Comment: @WilliamDunn i soon will be afk, try now pls

Comment: @WilliamDunn u have to check it not only in alert

Comment: ur trouble in select undefined element

Comment: this is odd because that value should always be greater than 0

Comment: if .length > 0 - it means that element exist and u can get .val() and .text()

Comment: u have empty elements in arrays - and its triggered erros

Comment: except if the element in the array is empty the alert shouldnt trigger its checking for it if (traitRequireStat0[key].length > 0)

Comment: so, its logical, cos it wierd - call methods for undefined